# Does Blender 2.8 work with Nvidia 1050 Ti graphics?

Tags: rendering

Having tried for weeks to get 2.8 to render on a Nvidia 1050 Ti, I'm stumped.
I have used many different versions of Nvidia driver, several builds of Blender 2.8.
I don't see where anyone else has got this card to be recognized either. It is supported in the documantation, & the card works great on other software.
But every time in 2.8 I get  "No CUDA compatible card recognized.
Is this card supported really? - It is recognized & works on Blender 7.9.

Yes, that's what I get - no card shows in preferences. But, on exactly the same machine, The 1050 shows for Blender 2.79, & renders very well. I tried the latest drivers, & several others, but it does not show.

Windows 7 (Home) 64 bit. All Windows updates. Device manager shows everything working.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your preferences looks like?[image]

If there is a card showing up there, then you need to check the checkbox next to it. If not then I am quite lost, since there isn't really a reason a gtx 1050 ti wouldn't work with blender, except if you have an outdated driver or something. As far as I know all of the 10th gen Nvidia cards work in blender 2.8 (I personally had a gt 1030 work fine).

P.S. If this doesn't work, please clarify what OS you are using.